# Unused Space allocated to table in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, database, database-administration

I have a table in my Database which has unused space of about 55GB. How do I reduce this unused space?

**Steps that I have tried:**

1. I have rebuilt the Indexes, this helped me a lot this reduced the unused space from 110GB to 55GB.
2. By running  DBCC SHOWCONTIG I found that my table's average page density is 99% (which is in a way good,but it did not help me to reduce the unused space)
3. I have changed the fill factor and rebuild the index again (this time rebuilding the index after changing fill factor to 100 did not reflect any desired outcome)
4. I tried DBCC CLEANTABLE (DBNAME,"Tablename"), I could not reduce the unused space
5. I have not tried shrinking of DB, I want to reduce the unused space without shrinking the DB.

**Current output:**

[image: CurrentOutput]

Desired Output: I want to reduce the Total space so that the Unused space is reduced.

Comment: Swethu, this is a DBA question. If nobody here can help you, you might get an answer if you ask on the DBA specific stackexchange site, dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: How did you get that report of unused space?

Comment: @Swethu Did you try  ALTER INDEX ALL ON MyTable  REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 100);  ?

Comment: Did you try cleaning the DB log file? https://support.managed.com/kb/a447/how-to-shrink-your-mssql-database-log-file-truncate-transaction-log.aspx

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have used SQL query

Comment: @AlexK Thanks a lot, this worked :)

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem. In future please actually post the SQL query that you used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON MyTable REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table and then export the data to this new table.

```
SELECT * INTO newtable FROM table -- or copy wizard (by SSMS)
```

And then, drop the old table, but make you sure that the all data was transferred successfully.